# Haciendo una funcion coseno usando series de Taylor

Tags: c

me dejaron de tarea hacer una función coseno en lenguaje C y no tengo idea como continuar acepto sugerencias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

utilizando esta ecuación como referencia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fact(int);
float coseno(float, int);

int main(){

    float x;
    printf("%f \n", coseno(2, 3));
    printf("%f \n", cos(2)); 

}

float coseno(float x, int n) {

    int k;
    float suma =0.0;

    for(k=0; k>n; k++)
        suma -= pow(x, 2*n)/fact(2*n);
    return suma;
}

int fact(int x){

    long i;
    long prod = 1;

    for(i=1;i<=x; i++)
        prod *= i;

     return prod;
}
```

El principal problema es que no me compila con este codigo usado.

Comment: Si puedes darle formato a tu código estaría super, para que los demás te ayudaran mejor. También si puedes comentar aun con más detalle qué haz hecho. Por mi parte, voy a darle con tu código enseguida :)

Comment: Por cierto, Por qué no te compila? Qué errores te arroja el compilador?

Comment: Que no compile no es una información muy útil. Por cierto, con `k>n` el for no se ejecutará ni una vez.

Comment: me equivoque al decir que no compila, mas bien me da a cualquie valor 0, como dijo mateo, el k>n era el problema que no note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que haría falta en este caso es saber de dónde llega la expresión matemática, si no lo sabes, te recomiendo este vídeo de [Khan Academy](https://es.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-14/v/cosine-taylor-series-at-0-maclaurin) o ver rápidamente [este artículo](https://economipedia.com/definiciones/serie-de-taylor.html). Que bueno si gustas estudiarlo más es la serie de Taylor, centrada en cero (serie de MaClaurin)

[image: Serie de taylor para coseno]

Esto es porque es importante saber que los signos `+ -` vienen de un `-1 ^ i` de una suma infinita, por lo que la fórmula hace necesario un `pow(-1, i)`

lo otro es `x` elevado a y un `factorial` de **2 veces i**, lo que se deriva en `pow(x, 2 * i) / factorial(2 * i);`.

Abajo te dejo el código

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long long factorial(int);
double coseno(float, int);

int main() {
    printf("Cos(2.3) = %f\n", coseno(2.3f, 15));
    printf("Cos(3.14159) = %f\n", coseno(3.14159f, 15));
}

double coseno(float x, int n) {
    double r = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        r += pow(-1, i) * pow(x, 2 * i) / factorial(2 * i);

    return r;
}

long long factorial(int x) {
    long long r = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= x; ++i)
        r *= i;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no tome en cuenta -= deberia estudiarlo mas apenas llevo 3 semanas y no comprendo del todo que es cada cosa. no pense en utilizar el long long debido a que no pondria valores tan grandes pero si es una función hecha generalmente si deberia llevarlo, debere tener mas cuidado acerca de esas cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Según yo, le hace falta el alternador que cambia de -1 a 1.

Así debería quedar (y le modifiqué la función factorial para que fuera la versión recursiva):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long factorial(long);
double coseno(float, int);

double coseno(float deg, int n) {
  
  double _cos;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  
    int factor = 2*i;
    int alternador = pow(-1,i);
    /* +- deg^(2*i)/factorial(2*i) */
    _cos += (alternador) * pow(deg, factor) / factorial(factor);
  }

  return _cos;
}

long factorial(long x) {
    return (x > 1) ? x * factorial(x-1) : 1;
}

int main() {

  printf("coseno: %lf \n", coseno(1, 5));
  printf("cos: %f \n", cos(1));

  return 0;
}
```

Y al compilar y ejecutar:

```
$ gcc coseno.c -o coseno -lm && ./coseno
coseno: 0.540303
cos: 0.540302
```