# haciendo la raiz cuadrada con algoritmo babilonico en C

Tags: c, algoritmo-babilonico

He estado haciendo la función de raíz cuadrada utilizando el algoritmo babilónico y me quedé trabado, al ejecutarlo me da números sin sentido
utilicé esto como referencia:

[calculo de la raíz cuadrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_de_la_ra%C3%ADz_cuadrada#Algoritmo_babil%C3%B3nico)

Primero solicité que me dieran dos valores, uno que es el que quiero calcular y el otro es el de un número entero que multiplicado por un número entero de un número cercano a la raíz que quiero calcular.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double raiz(float, int);

int main()
{    
    int x, y;

    printf("escribe el valor del que quieras calcular la raíz cuadrada: \n");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("escribe un valor que su potencia a la 2 de un número parecido a tu valor de x: \n");
    scanf("%f", &y);    
    printf("raiz(%f) = %f \n\n", x, raiz(x, y));
    printf("sqrt(%f) = %f \n\n", x, sqrt(x));    
}

double raiz(float x, int y)
{
    double r;
    r = (x + pow(y, 2)) / (2 * y);    
    return r;    
}
```

Lo hice como en mi publicación de hacer la función coseno en lenguaje C
lo dejo por si alguien la quiere observar:
[como hacer la función coseno en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/530075/haciendo-una-funcion-coseno-en-lenguaje-c/530100#530100)

Comment: El psudocódigo en el artículo de wikipedia no encaja con lo que implementaste. Como te indican en la respuesta que hay ahora mismo, no necesitas más que un parámetro

Comment: Hola Keyzer podrias decir si la respuesta resulto util, y darle un voto y marcarla como aceptada si te sirvio, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer el cálculo de la raíz usando el **algoritmo babilónico** debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
double raiz(float x)
{   
   float r = x;
   float t = 0;

   while (t != r)
   {
      t = r;
      r = 0.5 * (x / r + r);
   }

   return r;
}
```

Esta función recibe como parámetro el número al que deseas calcularle la **raíz cuadrada**, y mediante un **ciclo while** se van haciendo los cálculos correspondientes hasta que se encuentre un valor que elevado a **2** se aproxime lo suficiente al número al que se le quiere hallar la **raíz cuadrada**.